# OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available. at DataObjectSupport(721,6)

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I recently installed the latest Oracle Data Provider for .NET(ODP.NET 11.2.0.1.2), due to the fact that Microsoft Oracle Client is deprecated. Ever since the new installation, my SqlDataSource control stopped working. When I try to configure the data source and test the connection, it gives me the following error message:

Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection. Please make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is online.

OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available. at DataObjectSupport(721,6)

The connection settings are definitely correct and the database is online for sure, because any databinding I did manually works perfectly well. For instance, I can manually bind to a Gridview, ListBox etc. with ODP.NET and display the data without any problem. But I can not configure and use SqlDataSource control. This is painful because Gridview and Listview have a lot of cool built-in features. When you databind the controls in the code behind file, you lose all the features.

I have added ASPNET to Oracle home and grant it full access control, and restarted the computer, but it does not work. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and connecting to a remote Oracle database which is Oracle 10g. Does anybody know why I'm having the SqlDataSource problem?

Comment: You may need to add/change the `ProviderName` on the `SqlDataSource`. Did you do that already? Also, you may have to change the connection string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, it seems to have been a network issue causing this as it has started work again by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it editing the .csproj file.
In my case, I was using a project to connect to the database and in another application, a console application, I was doing the logic of my program and calling that library.
To solve the problem I've checked the section  of my .csproj.
In the database connection project the "Debug | Any CPU" property was different in comparisson with my console application .csproj.
I've replaced it by this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>full</DebugType>
 <Optimize>false</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```